# Cloudflare Conflicting Page-Rules?

Tags: caching, subdomain, rules, cloudflare

I have a website, say example.com. Couldflare is set to cache everything on

```
*example.com/*
```

If I add another rule:

```
*nope.example.com/*
```

And set it to bypass cache, what will cloudflare do with the conflicting page rules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Source A](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200172316-How-do-I-exclude-a-specific-URL-from-CloudFlare-s-caching-);

```
Page Rules are applied in the order that they are listed.
```

So, all you would have to do is put the bypass cache first and then the cache everything rule:

```
*nope.example.com/* (Bypass)
*example.com/* (Cache Everything)
```