# Is there a way to to solve several CloudFlare 'Page Rules' using only the 3x available?

Tags: regex, http, https, cloudflare, subdomain

I have a website, say *example.com* and require CloudFlare to redirect *all* traffic from http to https for *loads* of wildcard subdomains (inc. www); AND the apex (i.e. @ or /) but **NOT** for for a set of subdomains which are actually CNAMES to 3rd party services for which https is not acceptable e.g.

```
http://mail.example.com

http://calendar.example.com

http://drive.example.com

http://xyz.example.com
```

N.B Redirecting to the https protocol for those is not viable as it's not supported by those 3rd party services.

Looking into this, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30014528/cloudflare-conflicting-page-rules) solved half my problem. The relevant answer pasted below:

> According to [Source A](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200172316-How-do-I-exclude-a-specific-URL-from-CloudFlare-s-caching-);
>
> Page Rules are applied in the order that they are listed.
>   So, all you would have to do is put the bypass cache first and then the cache >everything rule:
>
> *nope.example.com/* (Bypass)
>
> *example.com/* (Cache Everything)

Each TLD domain cannot have more than 3x Page Rules though, so listing my *http only* subdomains as individual Page Rules is not possible.

Is it possible to create CloudFlare Page Rule with a logical OR in to target traffic for a specific whitelist of subdomains?

My thinking is perhaps I could express several rules in one string by using a RegEx to target each of the http only subdomains from within one Page Rule.

e.g. *as pseudo code with invalid syntax*:

`http://mail||calendar||drive||xyz.example.com`

How would one go about creating a valid RegEx to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer to my question is in fact:

- CloudFlare Page Rules DO NOT support RegEx
- The limit on the number of CloudFlare Page Rules is pricing tier specific

I discovered that currently; CloudFlare Page Rules do not support RegEx, Glob or any sort of negation. You can only use basic wildcard * or $1 to pass params.

It appears that if you have the same use case as me you have to just cough up enough money to get more Page Rules and explicitly list all the domains you need a rule for.

Current Rules pricing; 20$ for 20x, $200 for 50x, $$$X for NX - 
https://www.cloudflare.com/plans

Comment: there is also a HTTP header send by CloudFlare (PHP :: $_SERVER[HTTP_CF_VISITOR] => {"scheme":"https"} ) - you can redirect user based on this header to https:// link... it's not super clean and may be hard to implement to you code, but it can work.

Answer (score 2):

> It appears that if you have the same use case as me you have to just cough up enough money to get more Page Rules and explicitly list all the domains you need a rule for. Current Rules pricing; 20$ for 20x, $200 for 50x, $$$X for NX...

Page Rules are now available to [purchase a la carte](https://www.cloudflare.com/features-page-rules/), outside of plan upgrades.

Answer (score 2):

You could also just use CloudFlare as DNS only and bypass all the nice elements for certain sub domains.

I do this for my API.domain.com for instance where I want my own Origin cert from Lets Encrypt

but I want all my other subdomains to enfore HTTPs with the edge cert that cloud flare provides.